# Бот для телеграмма

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Всем привет,  написал бота для telegram, он не работает, можете дать совет как исправить, все заранее огромная благодарность, извиняюсь за фото , просто расскажите как вставить код, stack выдает ошибку, первая часть на картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 def main ():
        bot=Bot(
            token=TG_Token,
        )
        updater =  Updater(
        bot=bot,
        )
  start_handler=ComandHandler("start",do_start)
message_handler=MessageHandler(Filtres.text,do_echo)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle{}

if_name_== '_main_':
main{}
```

Comment: Советую первую часть вставить текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: В строчке if_name_== '_main_' должно быть по два подчёркивания с каждой стороны и пробел после if.

Comment: Неправильно расставлены знаки препинания, и, похоже, не установлена библиотека `telegram`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам необходимо установить библиотеку telegram, через консоль `pip install ИмяБиблиотеки` или `pip3` если не используете виртуальное окружение Python3 [Документация](https://pythoner.name/documentation/tutorial/venv).
2. В функции `do_echo()` неверно оформлены входящие аргументы, скорее всего должно быть так `do_echo(bot:Bot, update:Update)`
3. Не определена переменная `text`
4. После того как разберётесь с переменной `text`, уберите запятую в строке `text=text,` и добавьте её после `chat_id=update.message.chat_id`
5. `if_name_== 'main': main{}` исправьте на `if __name__ == '__main__' : main()`
6. Код оформите не в виде изображения, а по правилам сообщества - [Способы форматирования кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5860/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85), самый быстрый способ это воспользоваться горячими клавишами `CTRL+K`

Comment: ``исправьте на if_name_== 'main': main()`` - тут три ошибки (или даже четыре, смотря как считать).

Comment: @Эникейщик скорее даже так - `if __name__ == '__main__' : main()`